# Laravel: Order a model by "Has One Of Many" relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a customer model that has many contacts. I defined a relationship to get the most recent contact of the customer using the "Has One Of Many" relationship in Laravel 8:

**Models**

```php
class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function contacts() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Contact::class);
    }

    public function latestContact()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Contact::class)->ofMany('contacted_at', 'max')->withDefault();
    }
}

class Contact extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $casts = [
        'contacted_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }
}
```

**Migration (contact model)**

```php
class CreateContactsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreignID('customer_id');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->dateTime('contacted_at');
        });
    }
}
```

In my view, I want to **show all customers and order them by their latest contact**. However, I can't figure out how to do that.

I tried to achieve it via the join method but then I obviously get various entries per customer.

```php
$query = Customer::select('customers.*', 'contacts.contacted_at as contacted_at')
    ->join('contacts', 'customers.id', '=', 'contacts.customer_id')
    ->orderby('contacts.contacted_at')
    ->with('latestContact')
```

Knowing Laravel there **must** be a nice way or helper to achieve this. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have timestamps in your database?

Comment: Yes, I do. But in my case the 'contacted_at' column is the important column to derive the latest contact. Updated my post to reflect it correctly.

Comment: @maxiw46 can you post your complete model.

Comment: So what`s your goal? to show all contacts ordered by the latest contact? or you want to show only couple of latest contacts?

Comment: why you are not doing like that? `Custumer::with('contacts')->get()->orderBy('contacted_at');`

What's the reason to define a new method of the latest contacts when you can order cotacts?

Comment: @HemantKumar Sure, see updated post.

Comment: @VasoGamdelidze No, I want to show all customers ordered by the latest contact. Each customer has multiple contacts but only ONE latest (most recent) contact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the cleanest way to do this is by using a subquery join:

```
$latestContacts = Contact::select('customer_id',DB::raw('max(contacted_at) as latest_contact'))->groupBy('customer_id');

$query = Customer::select('customers.*', 'latest_contacts.latest_contact')
         ->joinSub($latestContacts, 'latest_contacts', function ($join){
            $join->on([['customer.id', 'latest_contacts.customer_id']]);
        })
        ->orderBy('latest_contacts.latest_contact')
        ->get();
```

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#subquery-joins

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much! Just one minor remark: 'customer.id' within $join->on() misses an 's'. It should be 'customers.id'. I was expecting this to look a lot cleaner in Laravel :-) But anyways... Thank you very much again.

Comment: Correction: I just noticed that now only customers are shown that have at least on contact. However, I want to show also customers without any contact. Hence, I think it should be changed to ->leftJoinSub instead of ->joinSub.

Comment: Yes, you can use leftJoinSub instead. I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is an issue with your migration, the foreign key constraint is defined like this:

Check the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Method 1: define foreign key constraint

```
public function up()
{        
    Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();            
        $table->foreignId('consumer_id')->constrained();          
                    
        $table->string('type');
        $table->dateTime('contacted_at');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });    
}
```

Method 2: define foreign key constraint

```
public function up()
{        
    Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();                        
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_id');                        
        $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
                    
        $table->string('type');
        $table->dateTime('contacted_at');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });    
}
```

Comment: In Laravel 8 the foreignID() helper creates an UNSIGNED BIGINT equivalent column. There is no issue with the migration.

Comment: @maxiw46 The `foreignID()` is typo it should be `foreignId()`. I will update the answer for your ease.

Comment: True. Nevertheless, the migration works fine. My issue is about the ordering of the customer models by it‘s relation. There is no issue with the migration.